# How can I pass symbolic linked file path parameter to Wine programs from a bash script?

Tags: bash, parameters, parameter-passing, symlink, wine

I made a very short bash script which start Virtualdub with Wine, and it can get a parameter too, the name and path of a video file. My script, called "vd" (it is placed in /usr/local/bin and chmodded to 755):

```
#!/bin/bash
wine ~/Virtualdub/VirtualDub.exe "$1" &
```

My script works perfectly, except when I call it with a video file beeing in a directory which is a symbolic link (or the path contains a symbolic link, folder name starts with ~, it was made by command "ln"). When I call my short script such a way:

```
VD videofile.avi
```

It is unable to open the video, because Wine is unable to follow the redirection between the symbolic link and the real directory. For example my video directory /run/media/disk-name/videos was mapped to /home with the command "ln". So what can I do to make my script work?

Comment: can you add the output of `ls -l` on the parameter you're passing to VD to the question? something like `ls -l videofile.avi`? It'll help give a greater understanding of the question.

Comment: Did you try `wine ~/Virtualdub/VirtualDub.exe $(readlink -m "$1") &`

Comment: Thx, I never heard or command "readlink"